# How do deselect all the file types in indexing options?

Tags: windows-7, search

There are tens, if not hundreds, of file types checkboxes under indexing options in Windows 7. It's a chore to unselect each checkbox. Is there a way to unselect all of them in one shot?

[image]

Comment: Isn't this the same as disabling indexing? Which can be done in Windows Services.

Comment: @Moab I am planning to add new extensions. I don't want any of the existing ones. or at least deselect all, select a handful.

Comment: did you try click-shift?

Comment: @Tony, ah, I have found no way to do multiples yet, sorry. Click-shift does not work either.

Comment: Have come across the same problem myself. Very frustrating, renders the whole thing useless.

Comment: I have the same problem... I want to uncheck all and then check only .exe and a few others.

Comment: i took me 5 minutes and a little bit of sanity to do it manually using space + arrow down .. :) worst thing is I don't know if domain policy will revert it afterwards :roll_eyes:

Answer (score 3):

I did it with a simply AutoHotkey script:

```
^l::
Loop 100
Send {Space}{Down}
```

Comment: BTW, you have to run AH with admin privileges.

Answer (score 1):

(It is a poor dialog and an excellent example of inconsistencies across microsoft software.)

May I suggest a keyboard macro, one where you can record a macro of space bar (deselect) and down key (next item).

I have not tried these:
[Download.com search result: 'key macro'](http://download.cnet.com/1770-20_4-0.html?query=key%20macro&platformSelect=Windows&tag=srch&searchtype=downloads&filterName=platform=Windows&filter=platform=Windows)